# Output Multi-line strings with Python Flask or other framework

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to take Redhat kickstart files and modify them in python before using them in a server setup.  My app uses python to curl the original kickstart file from my Redhat Satellite server then I'm doing a string replace on certain values in the kickstart file.  When I curl the file in python it comes back as a multi-line string, which is what I need in order for redhat kickstart to interpret the file correctly.  But when I return the string variable through one of these frameworks (web2py, bottle, flask) something is happening and it is not returning it as a multi-line string, I need it to preserve the exact format of the original file besides the areas I change.  I don't want to put my kickstart files in templates because I manage them through satellite, if I curl the file from satellite then it picks up any modifications without needing to go into the template ever time.  Then in a template or something I either return the string without a template or in a template file I only pass 1 variable to the template as the entire kickstart file.

```
@route('/kickstart/<name>')
def kickstart(name):

    ks = vula.kickstarter.kickstart.Kickstarter()
    ks_file = ks.getKickstartFile()

    return pystache.render('{{kickstart}}', {'kickstart': ks_file})
```

Here is the method in my vula package.  It returns the file exactly the way I need it. But again something is happening between this and returning this value through the framework.

```
def getKickstartFile(self):

    response = urllib2.urlopen('https://my-satellite-server/core-kickstarter')
    ks_file = response.read()

    return ks_file
```

I started off using Bottle as a framework but I found a statement that says they are not capable of returning multi-line strings, so scratch that.  I moved over to Flask but currently Flask is doing the same thing.  I am still learning python and possibly I'm doing something wrong, but I need any help possible to get this working correctly.  I would like to output a multi-line string.  I understand that you use either

```
""" or '''
```

for multi-line strings, but even after you do that and send it through a framework it will still print to the screen as one continuous line.  What am I doing wrong?  As a vary last resort I will be forced to put the kickstart files into templates if I cannot output multi-line strings.

Comment: How do you check final output? In console or via web with browser?
If via web of course you won't see new lines, becouse it should be `<br>` and not `\n`, but in your case of course you don't need <br>, you just don't see new lines but as for console it should be fine...

Comment: Ensure that the mime type of the response is what you expect. By default Flask will send responses as HTML, sounds like in your case you want plain text.

Comment: Yeah you guys are right.  I didn't think about the content type.  I have just recently started learning python and using some of these frameworks, so some times I don't look in the right places for my answers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Both Bottle and Flask can handle multi-line strings just fine.  Your issue is that your data is being interpreted as `text/html` by default and in HTML any combination of whitespace is collapsed into a single space when displayed.  In order to ensure that your data comes back exactly as you sent it you'll want to set the `Content-Type` header to `text/plain`.

In Flask:

```
# If you want *all* your responses to be text/plain
# then this is what you want
@app.after_request
def treat_as_plain_text(response):
    response.headers["content-type"] = "text/plain"
    return response

# If you want only *this* route to respond
# with Content-Type=text/plain
@app.route("/plain-text")
def a_plain_text_route():
    response = make_response(getKickstartFile())
    response.headers["content-type"] = "text/plain"
    return response
```

In Bottle:

```
@route("/plain-text")
def plain_text():
    response.content_type = "text/plain"
    return """This
              multi-line string
              will show up
              just fine"""
```

Comment: After reading your post I was able to find the documentation in Flask explaining this.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5):

Sean's answer is the correct way to go, but if you just want to test something you could use the `xmp` tag:

```
@app.route("/"):
def hello():
    return """<xmp>
              Hello,
              Multiline!
              </xmp>"""
```

### decorator version

You could also create your own decorator for this:

```
from functools import wraps

def multiline(fn):
    @wraps(fn)
    def _fn(*args, **kwargs):
        return "<xmp>" + fn(*args, **kwargs) + "</xmp>"
    return _fn
```

Then you can do:

```
    @app.route("/"):
    @multiline
    def hello():
    return """Hello,
              Multiline!"""
```